# How can i check if website has a new file

Tags: auto-update

I'm trying to make an auto-updater for my minecraft paper server, so when I start the server I would want it to check if there's an update.

Here's the code that downloads the file, how could I make to check?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd (server directory)
rm paperclip._jar
mv paperclip.jar paperclip._jar
wget https://papermc.io/ci/job/Paper1.16/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/paperclip.jar
```

edit: also, I'm on windows
edit 2: I found out that paper has API for this so it works for now at least.

Answer (score 0):

The http (and https) protocols do not force a server to somehow mention the version of the file.

You could do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd (server directory)
rm paperclip._jar
mv paperclip.jar paperclip._jar
wget https://papermc.io/ci/job/Paper-1.16/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/paperclip.jar
if [[ `md5sum paperclip._jar` == `md5sum paperclip.jar` ]] ; then echo It has not been changed ; fi
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am on windows, sorry